# When I try to revert a file using TortoiseGit, why do I a) get an unlink failure and b) lose the file completely?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, revert, unlink

I am not very familiar with version control systems, but usually I can use them without much drama.  This issue has me scratching my head.

[Unlink failure message] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhfHK.png)

("Unlink of file 'XNET Data Functions' failed.  Should I try again? (Yes/No)")

[Subsequent revert failure message] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24iJn.png)

("Command - Revert
Error - Unable to unlink 'XNET Data Functions': Directory not empty
Error - fatal: cannot create directory at 'XNET Data Functions': Directory not empty
Finished! Fail (1669ms @ 10/27/2020 3:19:31PM)
")

"XNET Data Functions" is the name of the containing folder of the containing folder of the specific file I am trying to revert.  After this revert failure, the file I was trying to revert will be deleted, and I have to use windows file history in order to restore it.

Potentially relevant information:

- I have no problem deleting the 'XNET Data Functions" folder directly from windows explorer
- this repository exists on a network drive which multiple computers can access
- this issue has always existed with this repository, it isn't a new problem that sprung up suddenly.

Comment: The message is not erroneous, in the sense that the XNET Data Functions directory is not empty.  But I don't understand why it would need to be? Can you only revert files whose parent directories are empty?

Comment: Please type/paste the full quotes of the errors for SEO purposes, rather than posting images.

Comment: Can you provide the repo?

Comment: There is some unique identifying information in it so I don't think I can provide the whole repository.  Is there any subset of information I can provide that would be useful?

Comment: I have determined that this issue depends on which user is logged in to the PC, which means it is likely some kind of odd server permissions issue. I still don't understand it but at least I know how to work around it for now.